# Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol '_CollectionType'

Tags: ios, swift

```
var desc = item.itemDescription
let regex:NSRegularExpression  = NSRegularExpression(
   pattern: "<.*?>",
   options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive,
   error: nil)!
let range = NSMakeRange(0, countElements(desc))
let htmlLessString :String = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(desc,
   options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros,
   range:range ,
   withTemplate: "")
```

and on

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, countElements(desc))
```

there's an error says Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol '_CollectionType'.

Any idea how can I fix this?

I'm running XCode 6.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `desc` is a String optional, i.e. `String?`. You can implicitly unwrap it in order to use it in `countElements`, like so:

```
var desc = item.itemDescription as String!
```

But note, that the `itemDescription` is probably an optional for a reason and that it could possibly return nil when there's no available item description, thus resulting in an error when you try to use it in your `countElements` operation.

**Edit**:

BETTER YET, conditionally set *and* unwrap your description string in one step using this nice feature of Swift called a ["Nil Coalescing Operator"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-XID_123) (introduced to me by AirspeedVelocity in the comments).

> The nil coalescing operator (a ?? b) unwraps an optional a if it
>   contains a value, or returns a default value b if a is nil.

To take advantage of this feature, simply change your `var desc` line to the following:

```
var desc = item.itemDescription ?? ""
```

Comment: That first `if` can also be written `let description = item.itemDescription ?? ""`.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks for the idea... But I think the syntax is actually `let desc = (item.itemDescription != nil) ? item.itemDescription:""`. Does that look right to you?

Comment: That is what `??` is shorthand for in Swift (in your ternary version you’d also need to force-unwrap `item.description`).

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Oh gotcha, I'll try it out.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity OK, cool. Very nice feature. Will add it to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: That, plus `?.` can get rid of a lot of the annoyance of having to `if let` constantly, means no excuses for implicitly- (or force-) unwrapped optionals :)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I managed to figure out that `??` is called a nil coalescing operator, but do you happen to know what `?.` is called so I can find it in the docs? And thanks for the tips! :)

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: Thanks! You guys give better Swift understanding to me! :)

Comment: @MohdIzuddinHelmiAdnan Please click the checkmark to accept this as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `var desc` must be of type `String!` or `String` instead of type `String?`

Just fix it and it should be fine.

The cleanest way would be to do this :

```
if let desc = desc {
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, countElements(desc))
    let htmlLessString :String = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(desc,
        options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros,
        range:range ,
        withTemplate: "")
}
```

Comment: The error says the type is 'String?' and your answer says "var desc must be of type NSString".